# Java: Trouble writing primitive data to a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to write primitive data such Int, Float, Double to a file in Java. Whenever I run the program the text file contains some random characters. I am using jdk1.8.0_25 and Npp editor. Here's the sample code I've obtained

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tad {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
        new File("E:\\temp.txt"))));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      dos.writeInt(i);
    dos.close();

  }
}
```

The output is not pastable here but it has spaces and some weird symbols which are not a part of the keyboard layout.

Comment: Well yes, you're writing it as *binary data*. It's not a text file at all. If you want to write a *text* file, you should use a `Writer` of some description, e.g. `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping `FileOutputStream.` Look at the documentation for `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: And here's the [relevant documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt-int-) you need.

Comment: When you write binary data as you have, you need to read it as binary data.  If you want to read it as text, you should write it as text, e.g. use PrintWriter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Random characters are the ASCII representation of the decimal 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on till 127, you can see the ASCII values in the following table where 0 = null, 1 = start of heading and so on.

[image]

Here is an example of what you want to achieve in my style.

```
public class Tad {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileWriter dos = new FileWriter(new File("E:\\temp.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      dos.write(i+"");  
    dos.close();

  }
}
```

and the following is an example in your style with a little change, I have used `dos.writeChars(Integer.toString(i));` instead of `dos.writeInt(i);`.

```
public class Tad {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
        new File("E:\\temp.txt"))));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       dos.writeChars(Integer.toString(i)); 
    }
    dos.close();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to "write" contents to a file, you don't want to write its binary representation.
So you have to use "Writer" Implementation's in Java not *"OutputStream"*

You see strange symbols in your file, because they are the binary representation of your data (ASCII codes).

Following code achieves what you are looking for.
Happy learning!

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

class Test123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Writer dos = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(new File("C:\\temp.txt")));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dos.write(String.valueOf(i));
        dos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code will only write (and overwrite) one line. I'll never forget struggling with similar code that had been writing to file flushing the content

Comment: Yes, this I suppose was only for the learning of OP, it does overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileWRiter. I don't have a compiler at hand, but it should be something like this:

```
import java.io.*

public static writeString(String text)
{
private static String fileName= "put path and file here";
try{
File file = new File(fileName);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true); //true means append to the file instead of purging the file every entry.
writer.write(text);
writer.close(); //close the output
}catch(IOException e){
System.err.println("ioexception: " + e.getMessag());
}
}
```

I'll check the code when I'm home to see if there are no problem, provided nobody gives better answer until that time, but this should at least put you on the right track.

NOTE - you should handle exceptions in IO

Comment: “NOTE - you should handle exceptions in IO”—funny note given that you are not making the slightest attempt either. The minimum would be to use `try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true)) { writer.write(text); }` to ensure proper closing of the resource in the exceptional case.

Comment: You are right of course, but I just wanted to make a minimal example, just mentioned it so op is aware of it (he said he's a beginer). I have a bad habit of relying on eclipse custom try-catch blocks that do everything for me(I know it's a bad habit)

Comment: The form handling the closing correctly is not more complicated than the other form, it’s actually shorter. I don’t know of any Eclipse feature that can do it better than the try-with-resource construct (which Eclipse supports, of course)…

Comment: True, exception handling is not complicated but I remember I had a problem with it in the past - I used to use it as a normal part of the code to get  certain behaviour - it was much later I've learned that it's a bad programming practice to rely on exception happening instead of using it as a recovery. I use just one of the auto completition features where I made custom try-catch block so that I don't have to type the part I always use (log, print stack trace) Not much, but in most cases if an exception occurs it helps trace it.